# Help with A Diagram of the Races & Mythology of The Lord of the Rings

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

I'm working on a flowchart diagram trying to detail the major races and basic mythology of the Lord of the Rings Universe.  My first attempt at this is detailed below:

[image]

**Are there any major errors or omissions thus far?**  (I understand that there are some overlapping theories, such as the origin of the elves, but I need to pick one to go with -- if there is a more modern, or more canon interpretation for anything I have, I'd be happy to hear it)

Comment: My only suggestion is to clarify the relationships a bit better.  Arrows seem to usually mean 'created', but my understanding is that the Istari *are* Gandalf, Sarumon, etc. instead of the Istari *creating* Gandalf, Sarumon, etc.  Maybe having different types of connectors (color-coded, maybe?) to differentiate created, related to, etc.

Comment: Out of major races, you may be missing Orcs creation link (presumably, created by Sauron or Morgoth???), as well as may want a separate node for half-Elf humans (like Aragorn). Also, halflings should be on the same level as Men.

Comment: Depending on how detailed you want to go, you are missing the Petty-Dwarves, the Huorns, and the Druedain. You may also count Entwives as different than Ents. Finally, there are the various subraces of the Hobbits (Stoors, Harfoots, Fallohides), the Dwarves (the 7 Houses), and the Elves (Eldar/Vanyar/Noldor/Teleri/Sindar/Laegrim/Silvan/Avari).

Comment: I would use a different symbol/container to differentiate species/races (valar, men, orcs, etc) from individual entities (Eru, Sauron, Gandalf). Then the relationship between individuals and species/races would be "is a". e.g. Sauron is a maia.

Comment: (a) Where's the image gone? (b) There's a very handy chart of the different divisions of the elves in the back of *The Silmarillion*.

Comment: The chart has disappeared

Comment: Closed given how useless this question is without the chart for reference. I wish I'd noticed sooner that it wasn't hosted on imgur.

Comment: I assume this is a new version of the image now. There should be lines showing that Eru created all the Ainur, not just Elves and Men.

Answer (score 13):

Of the types of beings that we know for sure not unique and are arguably sentient, you've missed at least:

- [Giant spiders](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/s/spiders.html) — [Ungoliant](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/u/ungoliant.html), [Shelob](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/s/shelob.html).
- [Skin-changers](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/s/skinchangers.html) — [Beorn](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/b/beorn.html)'s family.
- [Barrow-wights](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/b/barrowwights.html), maybe (they are very much like ghosts but I don't recall it being established that they are indeed the spirits of some other known creature type).
- [Water spirits](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/r/riverwoman.html) — [Goldberry](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/g/goldberry.html) and [her mother](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/r/riverwoman.html).
- [Giants](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/g/giants.html), assuming they do exist.
- Possibly the trees in the [Old Forest](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/o/oldforest.html), such as [Old Man Willow](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/o/oldmanwillow.html).
- Possibly the [Watchers](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/t/twowatchers.html) of Mordor.

Trolls, orcs, hobbits, possibly even men and elves (depending on how much you rely on Tolkien's descriptions to decide between cultural and biological differences between peoples) come in several subspecies.

Tolkien's stories also feature many unique creatures, some of which may be sentient: [Caradhras](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/c/caradhras.html) ([I don't think he's sentient](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17223/why-did-caradhras-not-want-the-fellowship-to-pass/17228#17228), but it isn't fully established), the [Watcher](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/w/watcherinthewater.html) at the gate of Moria, .

It's not clear that Maiar come in fundamentally different types, as opposed to individual differences; in particular it's odd to have separate entries for the Istari and the Valar on your diagram.

Besides Wikipedia's lists of [races](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Middle-earth_races) and [animals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Middle-earth_animals), the [Encyclopedia of Arda](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/)'s lists of [races](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/raceothe.html) and [animals and plants](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/miscanim.html) should help you.